# Render twig template more than once

Tags: php, twig

How do I render variables "as I go", rather than in one go?  In other words, what's the correct way to do this:

```
$template=$twig->loadTemplate('/theme/index.html');
..figure out $score
$template->render(array("score"=>$score));
..figure out $user
echo $template->render(array("user"=>$user));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just build options array as you go, and then pass it to template in the end.

```
$options = array();
//figure out $score
$options['score'] = $score
//figure out $user
$options['user'] = $user;

//render
echo $template->render($options);
```

Comment: That was my conclusion, thanks.  I was stuck in an old way of thinking, turns out my issue was not really an issue.